# How do I convert all columns to proper case/title case on PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I understand that in order to upper/lower -case all fields in a specific column, I will need to use the following syntax:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET desired_column = lower(desired_column);
```

**but what if I want to proper/title case my entire data set?**

Thanks!

Comment: Use initcap() function

Comment: The long way.  There are no functions in SQL to apply the same operation across multiple columns.  Worst case scenario; read the table names and columns names from `information_schema.columns` then use that to generate your new UPDATE statements programatically.

Comment: "*All fields in a specific column*" does not make sense. Do you mean "*all columns in a specific table*"?

Answer (score 3):

Use initcap function:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET desired_column = initcap(product_name);
```

Comment: I want all applicable columns to be in proper/title case though. How do you do that?

Comment: give an example please

Comment: I want ALL my varchar columns in my dataset to be proper/title case without the hassle of typing each column name out; as much as possible, I do not want to type:  UPDATE my_table
SET column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, column6 = INITCAP(column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, column6);

So my question again is... How can I easily make all my varchar columns in proper/title case in the most simplified SQL statement?

Comment: it's not possible in any database

Comment: @Angel The closes you can get is `UPDATE my_table SET x = initcap(x), y = initcap(y), z = initcap(z), etc, etc`